# How to Limit the the Days that Could be Picked by Ionic 2 Datetime picker

Tags: angular, datetime, ionic2

I am trying to Make an app with Ionic 2, Angular2 and Typescript. 
In this app i am compelled to use the Ionic DateTime picker :

```
    <ion-datetime displayFormat="MM DDD YYYY" min="{{startDate}}" pickerFormat="MM/DDD/YYYY" [(ngModel)]="Date" item-right></ion-datetime>
```

So what i want is to limit the days that can be selected via the datetime picker, like I want the user to be able to select ONLY Fridays, or ONLY Mondays and Tuesdays.

I didn't really find anything in the Docs that can resolve this, so i am asking for help here, any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify `dayValues` for more see [Ionic DateTime](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/datetime/DateTime/)

Comment: Well that is true, My app needs the days to be variable with the number of month chosen inside the same datepicker and i still didn't find anyway of doing this